# Standup a custom SAML IDP

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, openid-connect, saml-2.0

In our organisation we implemented support for OIDC and OAuth2 support recently and we used the node-oidc-provider library to support the same. This way our product acts as an IDP that support Open IDC. We were also able to integrate our product as an IDP into our organisations instance of okta for certain scenarios.

In the same way we are planning to support SAML2 implementation in our security product that currently only supports OIDC. Is this possible and if so is it worth implementing SAML support? One of the reason to support SAML is so that we can talk to snowflake where Azure AD will use our SAML IDP to authenticate users and then provide access to snowflake.

Or the other way is to use Okta as a SAML provider and talk to snowflake. The flow would be users connect to okta and then okta will redirect certain users with a certain domain to our IDP (Supporting Open IDC) and then once that succeeds okta will use SAML to talk to Azure AD which in turn will provide access to snowflake.

Please suggest a good way. If you say we can integrate SAML support also into our existing Open IDC supported IDP what is the best library to use for nodejs.

Thanks

Comment: SAML2 is a universal standard that many organizations already use, and it is supported by Snowflake.

Comment: Thanks @patrick_at_snowflake. My question is mainly about if we should host our own SAML IDP or use Okta. Even if we use okta, okta will redirect to our Open IDC IDP to authenticate user and okta can then talk to Azure AD using SAML.